# url doesn't change to the redirected page using header

Tags: php, html, url, redirect, header

my code in file signin.php says :

```
if(!$n==0) {        
    include 'home.html';
    header("location:home.html");
    exit();
}
```

But after i get redirected to home.html, the url still remains signin.php
So when i refresh the page, signin.php file loads again.
how do i make sure the url changes when the page is redirected.
thank you in advance

Comment: It always does. This means you probably have another issue. I bet your redirect ins't happening because of headers being sent and you see home.html because you include it at the top of this file.

Comment: you dont need to include the hmtl file in order to redirect to that page.

Comment: im using form action php self so that my error messages are displayed on the same page. Is that why my header doesnt redirect? Are there any other methods to post errors on the same page signin.php and then if successful, redirect to home.html?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot successfully send and enact a redirect if there is any output sent back to the browser before the `header()` call. You should also immediately `exit;` after making the header call. If you have a session open, you should also close it with `session_write_close()` before making the header call. Consider using output buffering (i.e `ob_start()`,`ob_end_clean()`,etc.) to ensure that you can redirect at any point in your application without having to worry about the output issue.

You can also read a little more about how the PHP header function works:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:
header("Location: home.html");
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer to help others learn in the future.